# How to open an Angular2 project from my mobile (same WiFi connection)?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I'm just starting with Angular 2 and I don't know how to configure the server to be accessible from a virtual machine or mobile phone connected to the same WiFi red. For example, when I start a Java server on my main machine in the port 8080, I can type in my mobile the private IP of my main machine, i.e. 192.168.1.1:8080 and I can access the content but, with the Angular CLI (ng serve) port 4200 by default, I cannot do it. I don't have previous experience working with Angular and NodeJS, anybody could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the IP address of the machine in the --host parameter e.g.

`ng serve --host=192.168.1.1`

Comment: I'm trying that option.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I need to read a little bit more the docs from the Angular CLI xD

Answer (score 2):

In **angular.json**, add `"disableHostCheck": true` as shown below:

```js
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "exampleapp:build",
        "disableHostCheck": true
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "browserTarget": "exampleapp:build:production"
        }
    }
},
```

Then globally install Local tunnel,

run `ng serve`

then run `lt --port 4200` in a terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel.

Assuming your Angular project is served on port 4200 AND you have localtunnel installed, execute this command to expose your local project under a public URL:

```
lt --port 4200
```

The command will spit out an URL that you can access on the public web (not just from your mobile).

Comment: That's a possible solution but, if I would like to not expose it beyond my private network? Is there other possible solution or library like that one?

Comment: Check out alexz's answer. Note that with my solution, your app stops being exposed as soon as you stop localtunnel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this will help me soon with public tests. :)